# Ngrok I am not getting response from server

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, ngrok

I  have a Dynamic web project in Java where I built a Web service. 
It is running in Localhost:8080 perfectly. All my services are working as I want, now I Want to Use ngrok to call my services from an Android App that I alreay did.

When  I run the line

```
ngrok http 8080
```

everything looks fine

The Session Status is Online, Version 2.2.4 and ofcourse two forwarding links
http and https
if I try to access to any of those links from other computer I get a 200 Http requests on my terminal.

And when I add the wsdl referene on my Android Proyect  I get a 500 https request on terminal

My wsdl URL looks like: `randomNumber.ngrok.io/Myproyect/services/Servicios?wsdl`

The problem is when I call a service  because nothing happens in the terminal and I never get a response, Also  I tried to call my service from a Java Client App on my computer but nothing happens.

What am I missing ? or what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the server along with the ngrok server in other terminal

**Terminal 1**

```
$run server
```

**Terminal 2**

```
$ngrok http 8080
```